# What is the function of として in this sentence? (Vたとして)

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension

From a [news article](http://www.sankei.com/affairs/news/160607/afr1606070040-n1.html):

> 福島県いわき市の建設会社「武蔵建設」の敷地に男性の遺体を埋めた**として**、死体遺棄容疑で同社の元社長ら男６人が逮捕された事件で、県警は７日、強盗殺人容疑で６人を再逮捕した。

What role is として fulfilling?

It seems like it may be functioning as a sort of *and*? My best attempt at translation is that we are just talking about:

> An incident in which a body was burried and abandoned.

But I'm sure I'm at least missing some nuance, if not getting it totally wrong. So what is として doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here として is "as", or "in the role of".  It sets a (potentially hypothetical) role and then describes conclusions/results based on that role.  In the quoted story, it sets up the "role/action" for which the six men were initially arrested.

Rough translation (abbreviating the company name and location):

> (For their possible) role in burying a man's corpse on "A Company"
>   grounds, on suspicion of dumping dead bodies, six former presidents
>   from the same company were arrested.  On the 7th, on suspicion of
>   murder connected to armed robbery, the six men were re-arrested by prefecture police.

For more information on this usage please see the section on とする of Tae Kim's Guide (http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/reasoning)

Comment: So then is attaching として to a past verb like that similar to attaching 容疑 to a noun as also happens in the example sentence?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "similar", can you elaborate?  I think 容疑 is more the "formal suspicion/charge/allegation" by the police themselves.  Eg, in American crime stories you might see "charged with first degree murder" (this is the 容疑).  But if you see "So-and-so was charged with first degree murder for their suspected involvement in <details of crime>", that "for their suspected involvement in" is roughly what the として is doing here.